# CSS3 sticky footer conflict with with jquery widgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have implemented a sticky footer using CSS3.It works fine for the footer.But in the same page I have datepickers and other jquery widgets which popout from elements.

The problem occurs when scrolling.

On scrolling the widgets also move from their corresponding position that is not needed.

when removing the sticky footer style especially

```
body {
    height : 100%;
}
```

everything works fine like the datepickers an pop ups stay in their respective positions on scrolling.

Comment: CSS and jQuery cannot conflict

Comment: Please post all _relevant_ code (meaning the code for the footer, psosible jQuery issues and the html, all seperately). If possible provide a live example (using [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) or an own site) and please make more clear what the issue is. When yuo scroll, the widgets scroll along, that seems like a good thing to me.

Comment: @Mr.Alien I think they were referring to the CSS from jQuery UI.

Comment: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/QGUbq/) . Here There is an replication of my issue. In that page the date picker which pops up on clicking the text box would move when scrolling, which is the unexpected behavior.
It happens while giving 100% height for body. But removing the height option for body will make the footer non sticky.